# Adding circles with different locations

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to add circle on my `JFrame` every time that I click on a button the code should add another circle on frame but as I use the `repaint()` method it always draw one circle.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);

    Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double();
    circle.width=50;
    circle.height=50;
    circle.x=getX();
    circle.y=getY();
    g2.draw(circle);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new PaintComponents();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==bt){
        String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a number");
        if(getX()==0){
        setX(100);
        setY(200);
        repaint();
        }
        else {
            setX(200);
            setY(200);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code.  I want to add many circles.  What should I do?

In this question my goal is to make a BST tree graphically by circles and line but I don't know how to add circles. I should show the Nodes in Jframe as circles step by step I mean that every time I add a node with an object it should make circle in the right location. How can I do this?

Comment: Well you're only painting one circle; you should actually be grabbing from some kind of list of circles which you can add to from your button's listener. You also never show your button's `ActionListener`

Comment: 1) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: I want add image but I can't. What is reputation??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't override `paint` and then call `super.paintComponent`, override the `paintComponent` method instead and then call `super.paintComponent`
2. `Graphics` is a shared resource, it used by all the components been painted within a given paint cycle. Be careful when making changes to it, like setting the rendering hints, as these changes will effect all components painted after this one.  You should be restoring the `Graphics` context back to it's previous state as much as possible before the paint method exists, better yet, create a copy of the `Graphics` context using `Graphics#create`, but don't forget to `dispose` of the copy before the paint method exists
3. Don't override the `paint` method of top level containers, instead, start by creating a custom component which extends from something like `JPanel` and follow step 1...
4. Don't modify the x/y position of the component (`setX/setY`), these are doing what you think they should
5. Create a `List` of some kind.  Into the list, add each instance of `Ellipse2D`.  When `paintComponent` is called, run through the list and paint each instance of `Ellipse2D`.  You won't be able to control the color, but you will get the circles to paint.

Comment: 5.  Create your own class with Ellipse2D and Color.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Had thought about that, but wanted to keep things simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) which shows the two common ways to do this:

1. Keep a `List` of objects to paint and then iterate through the List in your `paintComponent()` method.
2. Do the custom painting on a BufferedImage and then just display the BufferedImage in a panel

The link contains working examples of each approach.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is paintComponent doesn't work for top level containers such as JFrame call super.paint();
or instead you could just make a panel and add it to the frame and just override paintcomponent as you know it rest of the implementation is okkk to me